# MS Sql Server 2019 setup fails on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to install SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition on Ubuntu 20.04 by following - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver15

The setup fails at
`sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup`

And the errorlog logs below message. I dont get it. What parameter is incorrect? We only have to execute the above to start the setup.

```
2021-10-30 10:10:53.56 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU13)
(KB5005679) - 15.0.4178.1 (X64)
Sep 23 2021 16:47:49
Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) <X64>
2021-10-30 10:10:53.56 Server      UTC adjustment: 5:30
2021-10-30 10:10:53.56 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
2021-10-30 10:10:53.56 Server      All rights reserved.
2021-10-30 10:10:53.56 Server      Server process ID is 356.
2021-10-30 10:10:53.56 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file
'/var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog'.
2021-10-30 10:10:53.56 Server      Registry startup parameters:
-d /var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf
-l /var/opt/mssql/data/mastlog.ldf
-e /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog
2021-10-30 10:10:53.56 Server      Command Line Startup Parameters:
--setup
--reset-sa-password
2021-10-30 10:10:53.56 Server      Error: 17113, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2021-10-30 10:10:53.56 Server      Error 87(The parameter is incorrect.)
occurred while opening file '/var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf' to obtain
configuration information at startup. An invalid startup option might have
caused the error. Verify your startup options, and correct or remove them
if necessary.
```

Comment: Earlier, I did the install on a fresh ubuntu 20.04. Later, I did a sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade. And then started the sql installation. This time I did not get any issues.